# Trying to make a bash script that extracts html code from files

Tags: bash, scripting, grep

I'm making a script to extract html code from .html files in a directory which happen to have non-html code outside the html tags. I wish for the output overwrite the source files

Here is what I have so far but I'm having trouble getting it work.

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in `ls .`; do
if [[ $f =~ \.html$ ]] 
then
    cat $f | tr "\n" "|" | grep -o '<html>.*</html>' | sed 's/|/\n/g' > $f
fi
done
```

Comment: Please give some example on the data and the output you like to have.

Comment: You are doing `cat $f | ... > $f`. This won't work and you will empty the `$f` file. Instead, use some temp file or other approaches.

Comment: Thanks, using a temp file worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in `ls .`; do
if [[ $f =~ \.html$ ]] 
then
    cat $f | tr "\n" "|" | grep -o '<html>.*</html>' | sed 's/|/\n/g' > $f.temp
    mv $f.temp $f
fi
done
```

Comment: Parsing `ls` is quite unrecommended. Instead, you can do `for f in *`. Also, `cat $f | tr ...` can be simplified to `tr ... < $f`

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the whole script with:

`sed -i '/<[Hh][Tt][Mm][Ll]/,/<\/[Hh][Tt][Mm][Ll]/!d' *.html`

Or if you don't need it to be case-insensitive:

`sed -i '/<html/,/<\/html/!d' *.html`